# Getting only the first number entered for min and max, and no average

Tags: c++

Whenever I run this program, I get only the first number I enter for the result for min and max. As for average I don't get an answer at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Declare a named constant for array size here

    // Declare array here

    // Use this integer variable as your loop index
    int loopIndex; 

    // Use this variable to store the batting average input by user
    double battingAverage;

    double total; 
    double i;
  
    double number[0];
    double average[8]={.299, .157, .242, .203, .198, .333, .270, .190};// average of all 8 batting

    {
         cout<<"Please enter batting average "<<endl;
         cin>>average[8];
    }

    enter code here

    double max = average[8];// maximum average variable declaration

    for ( int i = 0; i <8; i++);//loop to find max average
    {
       if (max < average[8])
           max = average[8];
    }

    double min = average[8];//minimum average variable declaration

    for (int i = 0; i > 8; i++)//loop to find minimum average
    {
        if (min > average[8])
           min = average[8];
    }

    cout << " Maximum batting average is " << max<<""<<endl;//display maximum average

    cout << "Minimum batting average is " << min<<""<<endl;//display minimum average

    for (int number=0; number<8; number++)//loop to calculate the average
    {    
        battingAverage = average[8]+number;// sum of all averages
    }

    //average of eight batting averages
    cout<<"The average is "<<average<<"";//display the average

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: `average[8]` is out of bounds. You declared an array of 8 elements with indices 0, 1, .. 7.

Comment: You may want to review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Often a way to help a question like this is to present your reasoning for why you think/thought you were right. Why do you believe this code should have worked?